# tkinter - make a frame hide to the right with smooth "fading" animation

Tags: python, tkinter, animation, smoothing

I made a simple program where the main window has a frame `hideout` which will slowly move out of the screen

But it doesn't work

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('360x640')

hideout = tk.Frame(root, background= '#fff', width = 360, height= 640)
def initial(*args):
    for i in range(361):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        about.place(x=i,y=0)

root.after(0,initial)
root.mainloop()
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is way too vague. Please specify in what way exactly and include any error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using undefined variables: when calling `place()` on `about`, you probably mean `hideout`.

The "fading" can be controlled directly with `root.after` callbacks; use of `time.sleep` will block your GUI during an animation; this is undesirable.

Here is a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def initial(t=0):
    hideout.place(x=t, y=0)
    if t > 360:
        return
    root.after(10, initial, t+1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('360x640')
    hideout = tk.Frame(root, background='#fff', width=360, height=640)

    initial()
    root.mainloop()
```